# Cannot export uncompressed avi video imagej

Tags: java, export, imagej

I import Leica's `lif` file in imagej and after minimal processing (concatenate stack), I try to export it as an uncompressed `avi` video file. However, imagej automatically converts my 16-bit `lif` video file to 8-bit. Visually both the videos look the same but there is clearly information loss.

EDIT: A simple way to reproduce this is to open imagej, import a 16-bit video. Then go to *File > Save As > AVI > Compression: None*. The exported file will be 8-bit video.

Are there any known workarounds to this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem as seen from the comment line here- https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/blob/master/ij/plugin/filter/AVI_Writer.java#L183

ImageWriter plugin only supports `avi` video export for 8-bit. A useful suggestion by @imagejan as a workaround would be to use *Plugins > Bio-Formats > Bio-Formats Exporter* plugin.

I exported the video as image sequence instead of `avi`.

EDIT: This question was discussed briefly on [GitHub issues](https://github.com/imagej/imagej/issues/210) that's where this answer comes from.

Comment: In your answer here, it would be useful to link to the [original place](https://github.com/imagej/imagej/issues/210) where this was answered, to allow others to follow, and also know possible workarounds suggested on the linked issue but not here.